# Receive event for camera recordings

Tags: android

Is there any events which can indicate when the recording started/ended by camera, similar to regular sensor events?
I have checked the below document which details different sensors, but doesn't mention about camera.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview

My ultimate goal is to identify the time frame(in milliseconds) in which the video got recorded.

Comment: Is your app using the camera APIs directly or via a library like CameraX? Or are you trying to spy on the use of the camera APIs by other apps?

Comment: No, my app is not intended to use camera, it will just need to be running in background while camera recording is done through any external app. The data collected my app will be used for post processing the recorded video.

Comment: "The data collected my app will be used for post processing the recorded video" -- you may not have access to the recorded video. There is no requirement for an app using the camera to store videos in places where your app can access them.

Comment: The post processing will be on PC, the PC app will have full access to android file system.

Comment: "the PC app will have full access to android file system" -- unless you rooted your Android device, this statement is incorrect. Beyond that, there is no requirement for an app using the camera to store videos as a file on the filesystem. If you want that level of control, use CameraX or another camera library.

Comment: Alright, assume the end user can locate or copy the video manually it doesn't matter. All that i'm looking for is to say what time frame the video got recorded, For eg 1589634954252 to 1589634964252

Comment: Generally speaking, you have no good way of knowing that, unless you are recording the video yourself. You are welcome to look at file timestamps (e.g., creation time), bearing in mind that those will be unreliable (e.g., the file is a newer copy of some original recording made earlier).